# Modify emacs indentation behavior for comments in fortran

Tags: emacs, fortran, elisp, fortran90, fortran77

I am working on a fortran code. The sources are written in old fashion f77 style but the f90 comment style, with '!' is authorized. I want to edit the emacs behavior when hitting tab on lines with comments. I can distinguish 3 types of comments:

```
      program helloworld

      integer:: i,j

      do i=1,1
         do j=1,1
* This is a first type of comment
*    another first type comment
            ! second type of comment
            print *,"helloworld" ! third type of comment
         enddo
      enddo ! another third type comment

      end program helloworld
```

When hitting tab on each line with a comment type, I got

```
program helloworld

      integer:: i,j

      do i=1,1
         do j=1,1
*     This is a first type of comment
*     another first type comment
! second type of comment
            print *,"helloworld" ! third type of comment
         enddo
      enddo                     ! another third type comment

      end program helloworld
```

The behavior I would like to have is, as hitting tab on a line with:

- first type comment: do nothing
- second type comment: indent the line as an instruction line
- third type comment: indent the line as an instruction line, without adding spaces between the instruction and the comment that follows

I tried to override some function from fortran.el in my init.el but went crazy with lisp. I would be glad if some lisp/emacs warriors could help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want for your 2nd and 3rd type of comments with this:

```lisp
(setq fortran-comment-indent-style 'relative)
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook (lambda () (setq comment-column 0)))
```

For your 1st type comments, you need a *hack* like the following:

```lisp
(defadvice fortran-indent-line (after custom-indentation activate)
  (save-excursion
    (forward-line 0)
    (when (looking-at "*")
      (forward-char 1)
      (just-one-space))))
```

**EDIT**

Honoring your last comment requires a more complex and uglier hack.  **Replace** the previous `defadvice` by this one:

```lisp
(defadvice fortran-indent-line (around custom-indentation activate)
  (let ((type-* (save-excursion
                  (forward-line 0)
                  (looking-at "\s*\\*")))
        (type-! (save-excursion
                  (forward-line 0)
                  (looking-at "\s*!"))))
    (if type-!
        (progn
          (save-excursion
            (forward-line 0)
            (re-search-forward "!")
            (replace-match "__"))
          ad-do-it
          (save-excursion
            (forward-line 0)
            (re-search-forward "__")
            (replace-match "!"))
          )
      (if (not type-*)
          ad-do-it))))
```

Comment: Ok, it works for 2nd (except that the '!' is left in the first column) 3rd type comments (no extra spaces are added). Thanks! Any idea for the 1st type?

Comment: Yes, it's almost perfect, except that my 1st type comments may have more than 1 space between '*' and the first non-space character..
And if the '!' can "follow" the comment for 2nd type (and not be left in column 0), it would be absolutly wonderfull!

Comment: Still almost almost perfect. For the 2nd type:
1) if the cursor is located after the first non-space character as hitting tab, it does really strange things!
2) it erases every space between the "!" and the first non-space character
. Thanks again!

Comment: Works! The force is strong with you! Thanks a lot